# PHP - CSRF Protection with Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication, csrf

I need to create a login form with Symfony and protect it with CSRF protection.

So I use FormBuilder of Symfony.
When the user enter his email and password and submit the form he stay on the same page and the form builder send me that there is an error with CSRF Token.

If I debug the session variable and the token from the form there are different. But when the user reload the page it's ok those two variables are equals. It's like my session is overwrite or something like this.
The login page are on one url and the page where it redirect on another url.
Those two domains are on HTTPS.

[image: My session at first attempt]

[image: My form variables at first attempt]

[image: My session at second attempt]

[image: My form variables at second attempt]

This is the code of my controller:

```
    $userForm = new Users();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($userForm)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
        ->add('connect', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $userForm = $form->getData();

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $userForm->getEmail(), 'is_activated' => 1));

        if ($user != null) {
            if (password_verify($userForm->getPassword(), $user->getPassword())) {
                $id_user = $user->getId();
            }
        }

        if (isset($id_user)) {
            $redirectURL = "my-redirect-url";
        }

        return $this->redirect($redirectURL);
    }
    return $this->render('View/login-debug.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

And on my twig view I use the formbuilder : {{form}}.
So I hope it create the token in the right way !

I think I've made a little mistake on my script but I don't know where ...

Comment: Does it occur also if you refresh the page once before submit ? To be sure it's not a cached version of the page by your browser with an old csrf token.

Comment: @DiabeticNephropathy Sometimes it solve the problem. When the page is refresh everything work perfectly ! How can I be sure that my page isn't cached by the browser ?

Comment: I honestly don't know since the problem comes from the Client side (the browser). The "solution" I found is appending to the "Bad CSRF" error message something like "please refresh the page before login again". Since we did that, no complaints by clients anymore. You can change the message via a translation file, even from English to English. I used this method for that : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/errors-logout

Comment: Or else you could also put a hidden dateTime value in the form for you to know if it's an old cached page or not (NB: do not replace CSRF by a hidden dateTime !). If a user tries to login via a page generated long ago, redirect to the login page for a new CSRF token, but this time with a better error message. But it doesn't change that much the user experience than my last proposition.